# Text frame over line in Indesign

Tags: adobe-indesign, text

I'm trying to duplicate a header for a book project, but I can't get my text to go over the two lines I created, like it is in the example i posted below.

[image: example image]

I created two lines like on the image, but when i put a text frame over them, the text dissapears or goes over or below lines. I tried text wrap and that didn't help either.

Comment: can you tell what have you tried so far?

Comment: I created two lines like on the image, but when i put a text frame over them, the text dissapears or goes over or below lines. I tried text wrap and that didn't help either

Comment: Have you tried using a custom strikethrough instead? Check the strikethrough options.

Comment: When I use a strikethrough, the line continues under the text and i want it not to be visible under the text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solid Background**

Add the background color to the text frame. Select the text frame and then add a color to it. Make sure the text frame is above the 2 lines.

**Tip**: Create a character style that has left and right indents. You can then set "Fit Frame To Content". This will work great for varying text lengths.

[image: add background color to text frame]

**Textured Background**

Add 2 Rectangles Frames on both sides of the text.

[image: Text Frame Boxes]

Create your lines and group them. Copy and Paste in place.

Select one of the grouped lines and cut (CMD / CTRL X), select one of the empty frames. Go to Edit -> Paste Into.

Do the same for the other lines.

Result

[image: Result of paste into]

Comment: Thank you a lot Andrew, but the point is I can't get the text to show over the lines, when I try to do so, it goes over or under the lines or vanishes completely when it is supposed to be over lines. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JohnSmith I am not sure how you're setting up your document. If the text is under the lines then move the text frame above the lines in the Layers Panel. I do not know why your text box disappears when moving the text frame over the lines, things do not just disappear, so I am not sure what you mean. I would suggest you create a new document and just work with these 2 objects to see how they work.

Comment: I think you misunderstood me, the text frame doesn't dissappear, only the text dissappears, it's shown as overset when i move the frame over the lines

Comment: Moving the text frame in the layers panel shouldn't make the text overset... If the text frame does become overset, then you should adjust the frame size. I still do not understand what you're doing that creates this issue.

Comment: The text wrap was the problem, it was on so it forced the text over or under the lines, I got it now, thanks a lot